# Private repository without password prompt

Tags: git, bitbucket

I wonder is there workaround how to create private repository, so that other people could be able to git pull/push without password? The spicy thing is - it shouldn't be listed in user's repository.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Why didn't you ask this on their support forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With BitBucket, you would [create a team](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-teams-321853005.html) (instead of a GitHub Organization), where you [can create and grant access](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-and-grant-access-to-team-repositories-665225545.html) to the repositories registered in that team.

Note: you can [transfer a regular account repo to a team](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-or-transfer-repository-ownership-289964397.html?_ga=2.105587915.97412521.1514368268-453163493.1459227903).

But, for private repos, a [team is free only up to 5 users](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=host-in-the-cloud) on BitBucket.

Comment: So, there is no other option rather than create a group and share links.

Comment: @Reborn Not that I know of. Teams or Organizations have been done for sharing a repo amongst a select group of users.

Comment: that means, if i want to share a link i need to add person (wait about 10-15 most positive case scenario) and only then im able to make my business. Ok, assume that is works, but how do i then remove "Team" when it does no longer required?

Comment: @Reborn If you want to remove the all team, you would need to transfert the rpeo back to an individual account. If you just want to remove a user, you can do so in the team administration page.

Comment: Ok, seems logical.